# UIImageView not reverting to original frame

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIImageView that is positioned in a particular way. When the user taps the image, the frame is modified in order to enlarge the image. When the user taps the image a second time it should revert back to the original position. The way I figured I'd do this is as follows:

In viewDidLoad() I save off the UIImageView frame. When the user taps the image, I modify the UImageView frame to enlarge the image. When the user taps the image again I set the UIImageView frame to the original frame I saved earlier.

So, in viewDidLoad()

```
originalThumbnailImageFrame = imageThumbnail.layer.frame
```

Then, when the user taps the image, it gets enlarged and fills up the parent view.

```
imageThumbnail.frame = viewHeader.layer.bounds
```

When the user taps the image again, it should revert to the original frame.

```
imageThumbnail.frame = originalThumbnailImageFrame
```

However, for some reason it doesnt. It is positioned a bit to the right of its original position. What am I missing here?

I've even tried the following, just for kicks:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("toggleFullImage:"))
        self.imageThumbnail.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.imageThumbnail.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        originalThumbnailImageFrame = imageThumbnail.frame
    }

 func toggleFullImage(img: AnyObject)
    {
        imageThumbnail.frame = originalThumbnailImageFrame!
    }
```

The result being that when the user taps the image, it gets moved to the right while I would expect it to just remain in place. *confused*

Comment: Instead of setting the center, can you try setting the frame to originalThumbnailImageFrame

Comment: My bad, error in copy/paste. I am indeed trying to set the frame to originalThumbnailImageFrame :)

Comment: try to log originalThumbnailImageFrame as soon as it is initialized and then finally when the user taps on the image again. Do you see the same values.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the layer co-ordinates versus the view co-ordinates. I think it should be:

```
originalThumbnailImageFrame = imageThumbnail.frame
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to make any difference I'm afraid. But thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Curious. What about constraints on the frame? Are you animating the en-larging/en-smalling process?

Comment: I am animating the transformation indeed. I am not modifying the constraints Ive added in the StoryBoard. There is no difference if I remove the animation though.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comments above, you have said that you are applying transforms (doesn't matter if you are applying transforms with animations or without). If your `imageThumbnail` has a transform applied, `frame` property behavior is undefined (both for reading and writing), Here's what the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) say:

> if the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what this means though. I guess I was inaccurate when stating I apply an actual transform. I simply do a: UIView.animateWithDuration(3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in

Comment: it might be easier to read if you edited your question and added code there :-)

Comment: Yeah, I know. But the point is, I'm not doing anything except what I have in the original post. I tried removing all the animation stuff leaving literally only the lines of code in the OP and the behaviour is exactly the same. Maybe it's a constraint issue? Idk, but its weird.

Comment: If you are mixing constraints and setting frames directly, it can definitely give you weird behavior.

Comment: Maybe, but it still seems weird. Look at the OP for updated example.

Comment: did you log  `originalThumbnailImageFrame` and `imateThumbnail.frame` just before you make it full, are both values the same? There is a possibility that view laid out subviews _after_ `viewWillAppear` (`viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called in this case) and therefore `originalThumbnailImageFrame` now contains stale information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the actual frame, not the layer frame. So `imageThumbnail.layer.frame` should probably be `imageThumbnail.frame`
2. in `viewDidLoad` try calling

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
originalThumbnailImageFrame = imageThumbnail.frame
```

---

**Explanation:**
In `viewDidLoad`, the view is normally not correctly layouted yet, `layoutIfNeeded` enforces that. That means that the frame you are storing in `originalThumbnailImageFrame` is not the one that the view is actually displayed in.

*Alternatively* do your `originalThumbnailImageFrame = imageThumbnail.frame` in your `viewWillAppear` function. There the layouting has already been done

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, it doesnt seem to make a difference either. Ive tried both the layoutIfNeeded() option as well as putting the logic in viewDidLoad(). I'm so clueless right now. Thanks for bearing with me though.

Comment: You were close, it turns out I had to do get the frame in viewDidAppear() for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to store the reference to the original UIImageView frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` in order to store the correct frame.

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        originalThumbnailImageFrame = imageThumbnail.frame
    }
```

That did the trick!

Comment: instead of viewDidAppear, store it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidAppear` will only be called when view appears, not afterwards. But if view layout changes while view was still visible (e.g. in response to device rotation), `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called.

Comment: Even better! Thanks!